# C# TPL for loop - limit number of threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I want to use only 2 threads to make for loop. I tried this code:

```
ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions {
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2
};

Parallel.For(0, width, po, x => {
    sb.Append(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        double a = (double)(x - (width / 2)) / (double)(width / 4);
        double b = (double)(y - (height / 2)) / (double)(height / 4);
    }
});
```

But when I display `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId`, it creates more than 2 ids. I also tried add this code before loop:

```
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(2, 2);
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(2, 2);
```

But it also doesn't change anything. Somebody have maybe any idea how can I sovle this problem?

Comment: I hope you aren't using `StringBuilder` in a multi-threaded environment as it is not thread-safe

Comment: I use this only to make big string with all threads id. Do you think, that this StringBuilder make problem with running more than 2 threads?

Comment: Yes.  Just use `Console.WriteLine(Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId )` or `Trace.TraceInformation.....`

Comment: Still doesn't work :/

Comment: @MarMosh It wasn't meant as an _answer_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` sets the maximum number of *simultaneous* threads that will be used for the `Parallel.For()`. It does not mean that only two threads will ever be used.

Different threads can be allocated from the threadpool during execution of the `Parallel.For()`, since threadpool threads are specifically designed to be reused.

The following program demonstrates. If you run it, you'll see that the total number of different threads being used can exceed 2, but the total number of threads being used simultaneously never exceeds 2.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions
            {
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2
            };

            var activeThreads = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, bool>();

            Parallel.For(0, 100, po, x =>
            {
                activeThreads[Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId] = true;
                Console.WriteLine("Active threads: " + string.Join(", ", activeThreads.Keys));
                Thread.Sleep(200);
                activeThreads.TryRemove(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, out bool unused);
            });

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```